# Stripe Not Sending Email Post Purchase

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, email, stripe-payments

I'm configuring Stripe and have the whole checkout process working, except for the fact that despite configuring the 'receipt_email' variable, Stripe does not send me an email with the receipt after a (test) purchase has been made.

```
const response = await stripe.confirmPayment({
    elements,
    confirmParams: {
        return_url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}/projects/${project.id}`,
        payment_method_data: {
            billing_details: {
                name: name,
                email: email
            },
        },
        receipt_email: email
    },
    redirect: "if_required"
})
```

The email address does appear on the Stripe dashboard against the `receipt_email`, but an email with the receipt is not sent.

I've also enabled stripe emails as per below:

[image: Stripe email settings]

Am I configuring this wrong? Is there something else I need to do? Is it just because I'm on test mode? Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**

I found a [page on stripe support](https://support.stripe.com/questions/not-receiving-email-sent-from-stripe) which talks about the reasons why a person may not be receiving emails. One of the reasons says:

> **Ensure the email you’re expecting is for a live transaction.** Stripe
> only sends email receipts for payments that are made with your live
> API key or through your live Dashboard. If you are expecting an email
> for a test transaction, one will not be sent.

This would answer the 'why' of this question, but I find it hard to believe that Stripe wouldn't offer a way to test the email functionality until live prod deployment when real money gets involved. Is there really no way to test the automation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there really isn't a way to test receipts being sent automatically for payments created using your test API keys. This is mentioned here : https://stripe.com/docs/receipts

Instead, you can view or manually send a receipt using the Dashboard by finding the payment in the Dashboard and click "Send Receipt" under "Receipt history".

Comment: Thank you for validating. Is it safe to assume that an email will be sent out in live mode as long as the payment intent object on stripe dashboard shows to have the `receipt_email` property populated?

Comment: To automatically send receipts, ensure that the customer’s email is set and the option email customers for successful payments is enabled in your email receipt settings : https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/emails.

If you choose to explicitly pass in the Customer's email in `receipt_email`, then the receipt will always be sent (regardless of what was configured in your email receipt settings).

Answer (score 1):

In **"test" mode**, it's impossible to automatically send email from **stripe** after payment even if you set [**"receipt_email" parameter**](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data-receipt_email). Only in **"live" mode**, it's possible. *In **"test" mode**, sending custom email using [**webhook**](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders) is still possible from your app.

Actually, I couldn't find the information above on **stripe documentation** so I asked **stripe support**, then, they said so as I said above.